# How to sear or burn edges?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I've tried to make the edges of these shards burn with lots of different node setups, but I just can't get the gradient to work.  The goal is to get a real time burn effect during a fire simulation, that emulates a surface slowly turning black from the outer edges...as if it were embers in a fire or a lit match that becomes black eventually.  Thanks!

I've attached the .blend

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... Can you be more specific with what you mean by "sear/burn"? And possibly post some node setups?

Comment: Seems somewhat presumptuous to give such a vague question and expect a specific response, even posting your blend file as if we should just do the work for you.

Comment: Have you tried pointiness (geometry node in inputs nodes) ?

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite I wasn't trying to be presumptuous or expecting someone to "do the work for me".  If you saw my node setup, you would see that I've been trying to make this work.  Anyway, if you want clarification just ask for it in a constructive manner.

Comment: @ScottMilner, sorry what I meant was the outer edges around the shards to slowly become black and close in toward the centre of the shard, like a match that gradually become charred and black the longer it burns.  Hopefully that helped to clarify.  I've posted the node setup.

Comment: @lemon no I haven't heard of the geometry node or the pointless feature...I will check it out!  Thanks

Comment: You didn't have that node setup image and no I wasn't going to open a blend file from a stranger without knowing more details.